# PhpStorm Find Usage does not find out of namespace

Tags: symfony, namespaces, refactoring, phpstorm

Not only that but also Refactor > Rename doesn't change the usage name out of Namespace. However, it works fine within the namespace. I am working on Symfony 4 project and the directory structure and namespace are official one.

Find below an example:

The CategoryFixture class, when "Refector > Rename" or "Find Usage" is performed, it finds all of its usages under App\Tests namespace but none outside, because it is also being used in the fixture folder that doesn't have any namespace because it contains configs, it doesn't update or find its usage there.

[image]

[image]

If I move the fixture folder to anywhere under App\Test namesapce folder, it find and updates that fixture config file.

I want to update and find usage of CategoryFixture in these config files without moving them under App\Tests. How can I do that?

Find below my namespace settings.

[image]

Comment: This is not something the StackOverflow community will solve. Submit your issue to jetbrains tracker... : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The "Find usage" and "Refactor > Rename" will not work for a class that was created in a folder that is marked as "Tests" and used somewhere outside of the tests folder. It will not search for this class outside the tests folder. This is how it is supposed to be and I missed it.

The "Find usage" and "Refactor > Rename" will work for all other cases no matter if they are in the same namespace or different.

Also, both features do not work on YAML files. "Find usage" and "Refactor > Rename" will not make changes to YAML files. I have asked about this from PhpStrom support and they said it is not supported. This is true for PhpStorm version 2019.3 I am not sure what future holds for this.